# Match values of two columns with other two columns and return value in excel

Tags: excel

I have two tables (Table A and Table B). Table A includes name of state and country number in first two columns and specific value corresponding it (column 3) (n=300). Table B also has name of state and country number with several repetition (n=5425). I want to match column 1 and column 2 of Table A with Column 1 and Column 2 of Table B and copy the value from column 3 of Table A in Column 3 of Table B in excel.

Comment: If I understand correctly, "Table A" has only one record for each combination of state and country, while "Table B" has repetitions. If so, how do you want to select the third column of Table B according to the first two columns of Table A? You have a one-to-many relation. If my understanding is wrong, please clarify.

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @FDavidov Yes, Table A has unique record and Table B has reperations. I want to copy third column of Table A to to third column of Table B where records matches. Thus, I have one to one relation only. But I need to repeat where values are match. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: OK, ok, I understood it the other way round. Will post an answer in a couple of minutes. Stay tuned...

Comment: Can you use any helper columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use a helper column, in Table A Column D put `=A1&B1` if its an actual table it should autopopulate, otherwise fill down for all your data), then using `INDEX MATCH` in Table B, put the following in C1

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C, MATCH(Sheet2!A1&Sheet2!B1, Sheet1!D:D, 0))
```

Alternatively you can match multiple criteria with an array formula, so use the following,

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(Sheet2!A1&Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!A:A&Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

And enter by hitting `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`.